# Is there a way to use both @onfocus and HTML focus in Blazor without JavaScript?

Tags: c#, html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am quite new to Blazor, but I need to select the whole input field when the element is focussed.

In HTML, I can use this:

```
<input onfocus="this.select();">
```

The problem however: I already have a Blazor method binded to the @onfocus event:

```
<input @onfocus="@OnFocus"
```

I can't use both of them, as I get the following error in Visual Studio:
[image: Blazor Error]

This means that I need to find a way to select the input field somehow inside the OnFocus() method. I know I can fix this issue using JavaScript (JSInterop), but I hope there is somehow a way to do this without using JavaScript.

Current OnFocus() method:

```
private void OnFocus (FocusEventArgs e) {
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.inputValue)) {
     this.inputValue = Utils.SetDefaultValue();
   }
   Utils.SelectInput(this.index); <-- current working JSInterop method I want to get rid off
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain _why_ you don't want to use JSInterop? AFAIK It's actually there for cases like this. And IMHO there's nothing inherently wrong with using it... I mean, you're also still using HTML and CSS... everything has it's task and purpose...

Comment: I am a researcher for my company, with the task to recreate the client with Blazor without using too much JavaScript. I know that some functionalities needs to be done with JSInterop, but if it can be done using C# and HTML it is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this should work:

```
<input @bind="Value" @onfocus ="@((FocusEventArgs args) =>  OnFocus(args))" onfocusin="this.select();">

@code
    {
private string Value { get; set; } = "MyValue";


private void OnFocus(FocusEventArgs e)
{
    
 }
}
```

> Is there a way to use both @onfocus and HTML focus in Blazor without JavaScript?

Note: the @onfocus is a compiler directive which creates code like this:

```
__builder.AddAttribute(6, "onfocus", 
EventCallback.Factory.Create<FocusEventArgs>(this, (FocusEventArgs args) =>  OnFocus(args) ));
```

As you can see, this code, when rendered, attaches an event handler to the JS "onfocus" event, which is why you can't use it twice (causing error). focus or rather focus(), is a method that is called to set the focus, just as select is a method that is called to select text.

Note that you can use @onfocus to create an event handler from where you can call a JS function to select the code. This is legitimate.

Comment: Thanks! Never even thought about using the 'onfocusin' attribute :)